# How to create a common steps class for all feature file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

**My Goal:**
Due to there are many feature files will use some common steps, I want to create a reusable common step definition class for all feature file.

**My Code:**

Common Step Class

```
public class CommonStep {

static WebDriver driver;

public CommonStep(WebDriver driver) {
    CommonStep.driver = driver;
}

@Given("^I login to XXXXXX window title \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public boolean cadLogin(String winTitle){
    return driver.getTitle().contains(winTitle);
}

@When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" into search box$")
public void search_Screen(String cntrl){
    driver.findElement(By.id("idNEXT_SCRN")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idNEXT_SCRN")).sendKeys(cntrl);
}

@And("^I click Go button for search MERCH screen$")
public void btnGo(){
    driver.findElement(By.id("idGO_IND_1")).click();
}

@Then("^I navigate to a new window with window title \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public boolean navToScreen(String winTitle) {
    return driver.getTitle().contains(winTitle);
}

public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
    CommonStep.driver = driver;
}
```

Specific Step Class

```
public class MerchCreationStep {

static WebDriver driver;
private CommonStep commonStep;
private MerchPage merchPage;
private Merc2Page merc2Page;
private Merc3Page merc3Page;
private Merc4Page merc4Page;
private LoginPage loginPage;


@And("^I enter \"(\\d)\" letters of DBA Name$")
public void inpDBA_NAME(int num) {
    merchPage.inpDBA_NAMEStr(num);
}

......

@When("^I click New Button$")
public void clickNew(){
    merchPage.clickNew();
}

@Before
public void startUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    commonStep = new CommonStep(driver);
    loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    merchPage = new MerchPage(driver);
    merc2Page = new Merc2Page(driver);
    merc3Page = new Merc3Page(driver);
    merc4Page = new Merc4Page(driver);
    driver.get("http://172.16.1.68:8080/XXXXXX/servlet/app");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        // TO DO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Utility.switchToWindow("XXXXXXX- User Logon [LOGON]", driver);
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        // TO DO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    loginPage.inpBankStr("01");
    loginPage.inpEmpStr("200006");
    loginPage.inpPwdStr("Ajay123456");
    loginPage.clickResetBtn();
    loginPage.inpPwdStr("Ajay123456");
    loginPage.clickLoginBtn();
}

@After
public void shutDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Feature File:
    @Merch_Creation

```
@Merch_Creation
Feature: Merchant Creation

  Scenario: Merchant Creation
    **Given I login to XXXXXXX window title "XXXXXX- Main System Menu [MENU]"
    When I enter "MERCH" into search box
    And I click Go button for search MERCH screen
    Then I navigate to a new window with window title "XXXXXX- Merchant Details Screen 1 [MERCH]"**
    And I enter "5" letters of DBA Name
    And I enter "8" letters of DBA Address Line 1
    And I enter "8" letters of DBA Address Line 2
    And I enter "BRISBANE" in DBA City
    And I select the option "NSW " as State Code
    And I enter "1010" in Post Code
    And I enter "AU" in Country Code
    And I enter "9" digits Phone Number
    And I select the option "1   " option as Statement
    And I select the option "I   " option as H.O./Individual
    And I enter "V222233339" in Customer Number
    And I enter 4 digits number "5499" in MCC
    And I select the option "0300" as Branch
    And I enter "MCMDVCVD" in Card Plans/Styles
    And I tick the check box of Data Entry Mode
    When I click New Button
    **Then Navigated to window "XXXXXXX- Merchant Details Screen 2 [MERC2]"**
    And I select the option "D   " as Service Fee Freq
    And I enter "1.9900" in Service Fee Rate
    And I select the option "1   " as Payment Method
    And I select the option "T   " as Payment Aggregation
    And I enter "15" digit as Settlement Acct
    And I select the option "A   " as Settlement Acct Link Code
    And I enter "5" letters in Settlement Acct Name
    And I select the option "A   " as Min. Service Fee Code
    And I tick the check box of Data Entry Mode on MERC2
    And I click Update button
    **Then I navigate to a new window with window title "XXXXXX- Merchant Details Screen 3 [MERC3]"**
```

Features with ** before are common features.
How can I use these Common step definitions in specific definitions class? Can someone give me an idea about this? When I give common stepdefs a constructor. It give me an error about Bean creation failed. If I don't give common stepdefs a constructor. It comes up with an error about `NullPointerException`.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This really isn't the way to get the best out of cucumber. Scenarios should be no more than 7 lines long, and they should not contain anything about HOW you do something. All your steps are about how you click this and enter that, thats not the way to get the most out of cucumber

Comment: Hi Diabolist, thanks for your reply. This is my first time using cucumber, Could you pls explain more about how to use cucumber, or introduce me some examples. Thank you very much.

Comment: Its really hard to do that without writing a book. This sample project https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up was done for a talk at CukeUp 2013. Its in ruby (so you'll have to deal with that) but its very simple. In particular look at how simple the scenarios are for doing something quite complicated (registering a user) and then how that is used to support signing in. The art of using Cucumber is to keep things simple, but doing this is not easy without experience